# How to convert Expression<Action<T, object>> to Expression<Action<T, U>>?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have an expression that accepts a parameter of type `object`. I need to create a typed expression in run-time using a `Type` variable. See below. The parameter should be of type `int` so that I end up with an `Expression<Action<Program, int>>` which for a given `int` calls the non-typed `Set` method. How can this be done?

```
class Program
{
    private static Type SomeRuntimeType() => typeof(int);

    public void Set(object v)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Setting value...");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Action<Program, object>> e1 = (t, v) => t.Set(v);

        var type = SomeRuntimeType();
        // TODO: Create typed expression...
        Expression<Action<Program, type>> e2 = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There are various ways to do it. Depends on what you are really trying to do. What is the line after the `Expression<Action<Program, type>> e2 = ...`? Because the `e2` is now typed in some way, but you can't handle the fact that it is typed. Note that you could cheat a little here... There is an `Expression.Lambda()` that is non-generic. The `Expression` it returns is correctly typed (e.g. `Expression<Action<Program, type>>`), but is downcasted to `LambdaExpression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: from the C#-point of view the Lambda Expression is untyped (it is of type `LambdaExpression`). At runtime it is of the "right type" (like `Expression<Action<Program, T2>>`, this is possible because `Expression<T>` subclasses `LambdaExpression`)

```
Expression<Action<Program, object>> e1 = (t, v) => t.Set(v);

var type = typeof(int);
var par1 = e1.Parameters[0];
var par2 = Expression.Parameter(type);

// if type is a value type, you have to expressly box it 
Expression conv = type.IsValueType ? (Expression)Expression.Convert(par2, typeof(object)) : par2;

// We "chain" the two expressions
InvocationExpression invoke = Expression.Invoke(e1, par1, conv);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(invoke, par1, par2);

var compiled = lambda.Compile();

// sanity check, 
bool lambdaTypeIsExpected = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Program), type)) == lambda.GetType();
```

Note that if you need the `LambdaExpression` for some ORM or some other subsystem, not all the libraries support `Invoke` (that could be removed using an expression rewriter) or `Convert` (that is necessary for converting from value type to reference type). I've even seen libraries that don't like `object` full-stop (I've already tried these tricks various times :-) )